# Shelosha Ve'esrim Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows two hundred twenty-three?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The eighteen years following any non-leap year have 223 months.

Comment: Compare http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/6720

Answer (score 3):

Birth of Avraham until the Brachos that Yitzchak gave:

100 until Yitzchak

60 until Yaakov

[63](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=11&daf=17&format=pdf) until the Brachos

Answer (score 3):

Birth of Avraham until the death of Yishmael:

86 until Yishmael

137 until Yishmaels death